# GUI errors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Good day! whenever I try to simulate a GUI interface an error occurs:

Error in mathmeth (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)mathmeth('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

I don't know what does that mean?

anyways here's my program:

```
function varargout = mathmeth(varargin)
% MATHMETH MATLAB code for mathmeth.fig
%      MATHMETH, by itself, creates a new MATHMETH or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = MATHMETH returns the handle to a new MATHMETH or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      MATHMETH('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in MATHMETH.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      MATHMETH('Property','Value',...) creates a new MATHMETH or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before mathmeth_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to mathmeth_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help mathmeth

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 28-Jun-2017 17:41:51

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @mathmeth_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @mathmeth_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before mathmeth is made visible.
function mathmeth_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to mathmeth (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for mathmeth
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes mathmeth wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = mathmeth_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;



function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function edit2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit2 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit2 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function edit3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit3 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit3 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit3_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function edit4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit4 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit4 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit4_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function edit5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit5 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit5 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit5_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end

function solve_Callback(hobject,eventdata,handles)

a = str2double(get(handles,a,'String'));
b = str2double(get(handles,b,'Strung'));
c = str2double(get(handles,c,'String'));
int = num2str(c/b);
slope = double2str(-a/b);
set(handles.y, 'String', int);
set(handles.slope,'String', slope);
x = 0:10;
y = c/b - a/b*x;
axes(handles.axes1);
plot(x,y);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
guidata(hobject,handles);
```

Please help me! thanks!

Comment: this might have something to do with a pushbutton on your figure called `pushbutton2`. you can use guide and go to view -> Object browser, where you can find that button. Maybe delete it and create a new one, or just edit its callback. Also, why do you have commas in the `get` method in `solve_Callback`. Shouldn't it be `get(handles.a,'String')`?

Comment: I just did what you recommended. But its still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an obsolete callback function in one of your elements. This happens, if you add a callback function within the .fig file by using GUIDE and then removing the callback function manually from the .m file.

Have a look at all GUIDE elements (use the graphical editor) and check the callbacks. One of them has no appropriate implementation within the .m file (I would start with pushbutton2).

Comment: I follow your instructions. I start with pushbutton2. But still the same error I got.

Comment: I mean: start your search at pushbutton2. You have to compare the callbacks with the implementations within the .m file. Look through all objects and make sure that the implementations exist.

Maybe pushbutton2 is correct, then check the next object.

Comment: Ah I see. But where's graphical editor located or how can I view the implementations within the .m file?

Comment: Matlab Folder browser -> right click on the .fig -> "Open in GUIDE"

Comment: Well, it just going back to the "Guide". I'm frustrated right now may GUI don't work!